# Python Regex - Works in Expresso not in IronPython

Tags: python, regex, ironpython

Back to the same HTML thing as I posted already. Trying to learn a bit RegEx, even if I know there are other ways. I'm not dumb, just like challenges...

My expression is:

```
publisher.php\?c=.*?\">(.*?)</a>(?:.*?)<br\s\\>(?:[\s\r\n]*?)Date:\s<time\sdatetime="(.*?)\">(?:.*?)(?:[\s\r\n]*?)Pages:\s*?(\d*?)<br\s\\>
```

To match something in:

```
<p>Country: <a href="country.php?c=it">Italy</a><br \>
            Publication: <a href="publication.php?c=it/TL">Topolino (libretto)</a></p>
                Publisher: <a href="publisher.php?c=Mondadori">Mondadori</a><br><br \>
                    Date: <time datetime="1970-11-22">November 22, 1970</time><br \>
                    Pages: 196<br \>

                    Price: 150 Lit. <br \>
                    <span class="indexedBy">Index delivered by: <a href="mag-inx.php?c=ABo">ABo</a></span>
```

If I test it in Expresso, works fine, but when i run it in Python, my result is none immediately for group 1...

Any clue ?

Thanks,

M

Comment: Why are you processing HTML with regex?

Comment: Learning? Best way to get both Python and RegEx in my mind ? Because everybody says don't do it ? :-)

Comment: What does your Python code look like? It's not clear if the problem is in the RE or IronPython. Have you tried regular Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All implementations of regexp has subtle differences. That it works in expresso doesn't mean it works in Python. It could also be a question of having dfferent flags defaults, like for whitespace, etc.
2. Don't use regexp to match HTML or XML unless the case is trivial. Use a library made for HTML/XML like [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) or [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/).
3. Your regexp is huge and I get a headache from just thinking about trying to figure out what it works. See 2.
4. When you do this: `\\>` you create a backslash and a larger than bracket. The regexp will interpret this as a literal bracket. You need three backslashes: `\\\>`, or better: Use a raw string, ie use r'' instead of ''.
5. Use BeautifulSoup. Really.

Comment: ok, i'll give you a Tylenol :-) just for taking the time for answering. You know, I'm learning and need to make my mistakes... can't use libs, will stick to this poking around... thanks!

Comment: @Maurizio: Why can't you use "libs"? BeautifulSoup is pure python afaik.

Comment: @Maurizio if you can't use libs because you're learning, then writing a parser would be a better learning experience than masochistic regexen.

Comment: Can't use libs since the code is running inside an interpreter of IronPython where only the standard command are available... so long...

Comment: @Maurizio: You can install modules, you know. It's possible in IronPython as well.

Comment: That's what i do, import os, re, etc... but don't want to exaggerate. And with the dependencies, it becomes soon crazy!

Comment: @Maurizio: No it doesn't. Use BeautifulSoup. Really.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running it in Python?  Are you escaping it as a raw string?  Have you added the multi-line flag?

You are mixing double quotes, single quotes, and backslashes in a way that might cause problems.  For example this bit looks odd:

```
c=.*?\">
```

But it seems to work for me with Python 2.6.6 on Linux x86.

```
$ cat expresso.py 
import re

str = r'''<p>Country: <a href="country.php?c=it">Italy</a><br \>
            Publication: <a href="publication.php?c=it/TL">Topolino (libretto)</a></p>
                Publisher: <a href="publisher.php?c=Mondadori">Mondadori</a><br><br \>
                    Date: <time datetime="1970-11-22">November 22, 1970</time><br \>
                    Pages: 196<br \>

                    Price: 150 Lit. <br \>
                    <span class="indexedBy">Index delivered by: <a href="mag-inx.php?c=ABo">ABo</a></span>'''

pat = r'publisher.php\?c=.*?\">(.*?)</a>(?:.*?)<br\s\\>(?:[\s\r\n]*?)Date:\s<time\sdatetime="(.*?)\">(?:.*?)(?:[\s\r\n]*?)Pages:\s*?(\d*?)<br\s\\>'
res = re.search(pat, str, re.MULTILINE)
print res.groups()

$ python expresso.py
('Mondadori', '1970-11-22', '196')
```

Comment: that's the HTML code with all its idiosyncrasies apparently! confirmation that it works is good for me !!! Eventually, as I said, this is mainly for me to learn, refine and elegance will come later...